# Исправить логику

Tags: python, арифметика, прогрессия

**Задача**: мне на вход дается число `n`, дело в том что это число можно получить следующим образом:
Допустим берем начальное значение `x`, следующее значение `x + 1`, следующее `x + 2` и так далее.

`x` - натуральное число, то есть минимальное значение `x = 1`

Если поочередно складывать `x + (x + 1) + (x + 2) + ... x + m`, то гарантируется, что когда-нибудь мы получим `n`, основная проблема заключается в том, что количество таких членов неизвестно((
Задача заключается в том, что требуется найти минимальное значение `x`, при котором это задача выполнится(повторяю - гарантирутся, что оно выполнится)

Для этого я не смог вывести математику и написал перебор:

```
n = int(input())
nold = n
i = 0
iold = i
x = 1
xold = x
while True:
    n = n - (x + i)
    i += 1
    if n < 0:
        i = 0
        x = xold + 1
        xold = x
        n = nold
    elif n == 0:
        break
print(x)
```

Но, как я и ожидал программа работает слишком медленно с большими числами, можете помочь?
Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы помогли мне разобраться с математикой

Comment: `x` - может быть отрицательным числом?

Comment: Нет x - это натуральное число(то есть минимальное x = 1)

Comment: >Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы помогли мне разобраться с математикой - вот именно! Итак, У вас имеется m последовательных нат. чисел x, x+1,..., x+m-1. Можете сказать, чему равна их сумма?

Comment: И чему же равна их сумма?

Comment: Ну, знаете, это безобразие. Алгебра. 9 кл....

Comment: Кстати , если , я не ошибаюсь , в питоне есть же ж кв. корни?

Comment: Да, конечно есть)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101200/discussion-between-mathem-and-danilka).

Comment: Дружище - выбери решение и нажми на галочку. Для многих это важно. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 35  # 48, 50    

# ax + c = n
a = 1
x = 0
c = 0

a_i = 1
c_i = 0

while (n - c) / a >= 1:
    if ((n - c) / a).is_integer():
        a_i = a
        x = (n - c) // a
        c_i = c
    c += a
    a += 1

if c != 0:
    print(' + '.join([str(x)] + ['({0} + {1})'.format(x, coeff) for coeff in range(1, a_i)]), '=', n)
else:
    print(x, '=', n)

# 2 + (2 + 1) + (2 + 2) + (2 + 3) + (2 + 4) + (2 + 5) + (2 + 6) = 35
# 8 + (8 + 1) + (8 + 2) + (8 + 3) + (8 + 4) = 50
# 15 + (15 + 1) + (15 + 2) = 48
```

**Еще вариант**:

```
import math


n = 3  # 34, 36, 1569

c = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
a = c + 1
c_n = sum(range(1, a))


if c_n == n:
    x = 1
else:
    x = n
    for c_i in range(c, 0, -1):
        if ((n - c_n) / (c_i + 1)) % 1 == 0:
            c = c_i + 1
            x = (n - c_n) // c
            break
        c_n -= c_i

if c != 0:
    print(' + '.join([str(x)] + ['({0} + {1})'.format(x, c_i) for c_i in range(1, c)]), '=', n)
else:
    print(x, '=', n)

# 1 + (1 + 1) = 3
# 7 + (7 + 1) + (7 + 2) + (7 + 3) = 34
# 1 + (1 + 1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 3) + (1 + 4) + (1 + 5) + (1 + 6) + (1 + 7) = 36
# 259 + (259 + 1) + (259 + 2) + (259 + 3) + (259 + 4) + (259 + 5) = 1569
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно немного поднатужиться, и нати *все* такие разложения заданного числа `z`. Понятно, что задача переформулируется так:
"для заданного числа `z`найти такие целые `n` и `x` , что верно
 `z=n*x + (n-1)*n/2`".  Преобразовывая, понимаем, что
 `x = z/n - (n-1)/2`. Или другими словами `n` является делителем числа `2*z`.
Тогда задача сводится к следующему:
найти из всех делителей числа `2*z`, такие, которые удовлетворяют целочисленному уравнению  `z=n*x + (n-1)*n/2`".
[Здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python-science/thread2210080.html) берем код для построения списка всех делителей числа, и в итоге получаем такое решение:

Все решение сводится к следующему коду:

```
z = int(input("n="))

divisors_l = divisors(z*2)

for n in divisors_l[1:]:
    x = z//n - (n-1)//2
    if x<0: break
    print(f"x={x}")
    if z == n*x + (n-1)*n//2:
        print(f"yes! n={n}, x={x}")
        expantion(x,n,z)
```

Я использовал также код для разложения в ряд автора @slippyk. 
все остальное - использование "стандартных" функций))
полный код приведен ниже.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov 19 22:20:39 2019

@author: Vasil
"""

from collections import Counter

def get_ls(n):
    """Разложить число на множители"""
    #result = [1]
    result = []
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            n //= i
            result.append(i)
        else:
            i += 1
    if n > 1:
        result.append(n)
    return result

def divisors(n):
    ls = get_ls(n)
    kkk = dict(Counter(ls)).items()

    d = [k for k, _ in kkk]
    m = [v for _, v in kkk]
    k = [0 for _ in range(len(set(ls)))]

    result = []
    ln = range(len(m))

    try:
        while True:
            r = 1
            for i1, i2 in zip(d, k):
                r *= i1 ** i2
#            print(r)
            result.append(r)

            k[0] += 1
            for i in ln:
                if k[i] > m[i]:
                    k[i] = 0
                    k[i+1] += 1  # IndexError
    except IndexError:
        pass 
    return sorted(result)

#divisors_l = divisors(int(input("n=")))

def expantion(x,c,n):
    if c != 0:
        print(' + '.join([str(x)] +  \
            ['({0} + {1})'.format(x, c_i) for c_i in range(1, c)]), 
            '=', n)
    else:
        print(x, '=', n)

z = int(input("n="))

divisors_l = divisors(z*2)

for n in divisors_l[1:]:
    x = z//n - (n-1)//2
    if x<0: break
    print(f"x={x}")
    if z == n*x + (n-1)*n//2:
        print(f"yes! n={n}, x={x}")
        expantion(x,n,z)
```

Это решение дает например:

```
n=1569
x=784
yes! n=2, x=784
784 + (784 + 1) = 1569
x=522
yes! n=3, x=522
522 + (522 + 1) + (522 + 2) = 1569
x=259
yes! n=6, x=259
259 + (259 + 1) + (259 + 2) + (259 + 3) + (259 + 4) + (259 + 5) = 1569
```

или для 50:

```
n=50
x=25
x=11
yes! n=4, x=11
11 + (11 + 1) + (11 + 2) + (11 + 3) = 50
x=8
yes! n=5, x=8
8 + (8 + 1) + (8 + 2) + (8 + 3) + (8 + 4) = 50
x=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ @VasylKolomiets также интересен тем, что можно сделать некоторые выводы о том, какими должны быть z, n и x, сокращая время на перебор.
посмотрите на формулу **x = z/n - (n-1)/2**

Чтоб х было целым должны выполняться условия:

1. **n** четным быть не может, а потому перебирать требуется только нечетные. Более того, нас интересуют только простые, чтоб потом проверить частное от деления **z** на них. А когда ищем простые, то гораздо быстрее будет двигаться по числам из ряда **(2*3*m)+-1**
2. поскольку **х** должен быть больше нуля, **z>(n-1)n/2**, или **2z>n(n-1)**, то есть **n** должен быть меньше **sqrt(2z)+1**, так что от него и можем стартовать перебор.
3. наконец, **z** обязан нацело делиться на **n**, то есть нужно просто идти по ряду простых чисел в поисках делителей. Идти потребуется от самого большого из возможных **n** (помним, что задача найти наименьший **х**, а это достигается при наибольшем **n**), то есть стартуем от **n = sqrt(2z)+1** вниз, к 1

Поставьте, пож., плюсик @VasylKolomiets, поскольку это выводы из его расчета.